# Enable mbstring library for PHP Windows installation

Tags: php, php-ini, mbstring

Using php 8.20 X86 Win32 VS16 not thread safe

In PHP.ini I have

```
extension=mbstring
```

(i.e. uncommented ";" in front)

and

```
extension_dir = "D:\webserve\php8X86Win32VS16NTS\ext"
```

In file system I have:
file `php_mbstring.dll`
in:
directory `D:\webserve\php8X86Win32VS16NTS\ext`

...

PHPInfo()

- states it is using the php.ini file I have edited.
- extension direct is "ext" (which it is if if I use fully qualitfied
  path in php.ini)

...

Yet I still get error in code:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Stichoza\GoogleTranslate\Tokens\mb_strlen()

...

What is the next thing I should check in my configuration to get multibyte string support working in PHP?

Comment: You might look at [log_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log). When configured errors are written to a file, which might provide why you have an error.

Comment: BTW: I have the 64bit version (installed via [Choco](https://chocolatey.org/) ), and `mb_strlen` does work on my Windows system.  I have in my php.ini: `;extension=mbstring`, so the extension is not enabled, and still `print mb_strlen('tést').'-'.strlen('tést');`  returns "4-5".

Comment: What is the exact line of code that is causing the error? Normally you wouldn't see a namespace (?) like `Stichoza\GoogleTranslate\Tokens` in front of a globally defined function name.

Comment: After changing the `php.ini` file, did you restart the webserver? ... this is necessary after _any edit_ to php.ini.

Comment: I think something odd is going on with my Apache/PHP. Problem resolved itself after returning to the computer many hours later... But now I have the same problem with getting error "CURLOPT_URL" not defined / then uncommenting extension curl extension. Now even efter uncommenting so Curl should load... And restarting server... This returns false: function_exists('curl_version') ... I have tried in task manager shutdown Apache but well... I will return tomorrow or sooner. If a reset works, I know something odd is going on.